# How to use "group by" in Orange.. i.e. can i "group by" table values?

Tags: orange

Regarding the Orange Data Science platform
I can't find any method for aggregate functions on data tables. That is, I'd like to sum the numbers of a given categorical value in a dataset (how many instances of a particular flower for example). 
Is there any way to do this without resorting to python script?
Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way in the UI to do this other than a python script - but wanted to encourage you to consider using a script, because with pandas it doesn't require much:

```
import pandas as pd
from Orange.data.pandas_compat import table_from_frame

#read file into Orange
newData = pd.read_csv('yourfile.tab', sep=chr(0x09))

#group data on categories in 'column'
grouped = newData.groupby('column')

#calculate the sum from the grouping, convert to Orange table and set to out_data
out_data = table_from_frame(grouped.sum())
```

Pros:
opens up many possibilities to load / manipulate your data

Cons:
the approach only works loading a file using python, as I haven't determined how to change an Orange table into a pandas dataframe so it can use in_data instead.

Comment: Thanks Creo. I was really hoping that the IDE would have it all in there as that makes it more likely business analysts could use it effectively.